# Align icon and the title in Listview item

Tags: android

Im designing my interfaces for my research project on android. So I added facebook kind side navigation listview. But when the itesms are added to the list view it will not get align center horizontally..I need to get the icon origin and the title in a same horizontal line. Please be kind enough to provide me a solution for my problem. Below provided my code. I'm sorry about my english.

Here is an image of my current interface. Please refer settings button. The settings word is bit upside. I need both icon and settings word aligh horizontally in same line.

[image is here http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/485944_4792129535506_1863888545_n.jpg](http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/485944_4792129535506_1863888545_n.jpg)

`slide.xml` - all the items for the listview are included here

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title="@string/item_one"
    android:top="30dp"
   >
</item>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/item_two"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_three">
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_three"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_three">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_four"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_four">
</item>

 <item
    android:id="@+id/item_five"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_one">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_six"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_two">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_seven"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_three">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/item_eight"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/item_four"
   >
</item>
</menu>
```

`slidemenu.xml` - the listview is here

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="260dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#2c323f"

         >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:background="#2c323f"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:listSelector="#454b5d"
            android:divider="@layout/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1sp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#2c323f"

             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my activity class

```
package com.coboltforge.slidemenuexample;

import com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu;
import com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenu.SlideMenuItem;
import com.coboltforge.slidemenu.SlideMenuInterface.OnSlideMenuItemClickListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSlideMenuItemClickListener {

    private SlideMenu slidemenu;
    private final static int MYITEMID = 42;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*
         * There are two ways to add the slide menu: 
         * From code or to inflate it from XML (then you have to declare it in the activities layout XML)
         */
        // this is from code. no XML declaration necessary, but you won't get state restored after rotation.
//      slidemenu = new SlideMenu(this, R.menu.slide, this, 333);
        // this inflates the menu from XML. open/closed state will be restored after rotation, but you'll have to call init.
        slidemenu = (SlideMenu) findViewById(R.id.slideMenu);
        slidemenu.init(this, R.menu.slide, this, 333);

        // this can set the menu to initially shown instead of hidden
//      slidemenu.setAsShown(); 

        // set optional header image
        slidemenu.setHeaderImage(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        // this demonstrates how to dynamically add menu items
        SlideMenuItem item = new SlideMenuItem();
        item.id = MYITEMID;
        item.icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        item.label = "Dynamically added item";
        slidemenu.addMenuItem(item);

        // connect the fallback button in case there is no ActionBar
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMenu);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                slidemenu.show();
            }
        });

    }



    public void onSlideMenuItemClick(int itemId) {

        switch(itemId) {
        case R.id.item_one:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item one selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.item_two:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item two selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.item_three:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item three selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.item_four:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Item four selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MYITEMID:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dynamically added item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: // this is the app icon of the actionbar
            slidemenu.show();
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest using SlidingMenu library. It offers much more customization and yes, it would allow you to correct that problem very easily. Also, very importantly, it follows Google's approved way for the Side Drawer UI pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the settings word is bit upside. I need both icon and settings word
>   aligh horizontally in same line

I'm guessing you use [this library](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu). The problem is that you can't access the layout file that is used for the row view of the sliding menu adapter to modify it. But you can easily solve this if you copy the library's code(which consists of very few files) and put it directly in your project. Then modify the `slidemenu_listitem.xml` file like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"

        android:textSize="24dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Of course, you can always make a feature request to the user how made the library to modify it so you can insert your own layout file in the library(and wait for that to happen).

Comment: thank you for your comment. I got a point from your answer. I found a method to modify the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
android:gravity="center" (or top/bottom/left/right depending your needs)
```

of your textview to align text where you want.

> layout_gravity sets the gravity (alignment) of the View or Layout
>   inside its parent. If you have a text view inside a linear layout,
>   then setting the layout_gravity of the text view will alter its
>   alignment in the layout. gravity sets the alignment of the content of
>   the view or layout it is applied on. If you want your text (in the
>   text view) to be left aligned, center, or right aligned, then modify
>   the gravity attribute of the text view.

From: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/